# Parse incoming mail in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, parsing

I need to parse the title of incoming mails and do some simple checks like "does it include this word/number".

I'm familiar with AutoHotkey, batch, PHP...

Any ideas? I can't seem to find a plugin to auto export email as `.txt` files, that would really make things easy. Apparently Thunderbird is using the "mbox" format for storage.

Comment: have you already given up on t-birds filter feature?

Comment: It's not advanced enough for my purposes - I will probably extract some info from an INF file and then compare stuff etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a solution and found two:

The Thunderbird add-on [ImportExportTools](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/) will export emails into plain text; either concatenated into a single text file or per email. It also supports exporting as EML, HTML, CSV, and PDF. Scheduling can be setup within the addon to automatically export.

I also found [mimekit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/), a .NET parser library to directly parse the mbox file. Development didn't start until after you asked your question though (October 2012) if that makes you feel better.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using FiltaQuilla to filter message and save them to specified folder.
Then execute external file to process and delete them.

This help me to generate my credit card bill automatically.